# Why a free variable value in closure only returns the initial value when it is accessed directly?

Tags: javascript, closures

```
function Counter() {
  var c = 0;
  function increment() {
    c++;
  }
  function getC() {
    return c;
  }
  return { increment, getC, c };
}

var { increment, getC, c } = Counter();
increment();
increment();
increment();
increment();
console.log(getC());        // 4
console.log(c);             // 0
```

I am confused with the behavior above, especially the last line.

I expected `c` also returns `4` as well as `getC()` but it only returns the initial value which is 0.

Could somebody help me understanding what is going on behind the scene?

Comment: When you use `var { increment, getC, c } = Counter();` you create new variable `c` and since numbers are passed by value and not by reference you are not modifying the same c value from inside the Counter.

Comment: You could equally have written `return { increment, getC, c: 0 }`. Object properties are not references, `.c` is holding a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass `c` into `return { increment, getC, c }`, `c` passes its value and not its reference due to it being a primitive type (simple e.g.: numbers, strings).

Therefore function return will not be changed by subsequent function calls.
Note that the reason `getC` works is because the function accesses the original `c` reference, not just the value.